# Shiny DataTable row selection responding to user input

Tags: shiny, row, selection, user-input, dt

I'm having problems selecting a row in a DataTable via user input. I'm using dev versions of Shiny and DT because row selection isn't working in non-dev versions. Specifically, I'm using Shiny ‘0.13.2.9004’ and DT ‘0.1.56’. Consider this app:

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textOutput('row'),
      numericInput('selectRow', 'selectRow', 3)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DT::dataTableOutput('testTable')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$testTable <- DT::renderDataTable(iris,
                                          selection = list(mode = 'single',
                                                           target = 'row',
                                                           selected = as.character(input$selectRow)),
                                          server = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

When it runs, the third row of `testTable` is selected because that's the default value of `selectRow`. But changing the value of `selectRow` does nothing to the row selection in `testTable`. Bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `selected` option only works for pre-selection. To update selection after table is created, you need to use `dataTableProxy` and `selectRows`. Add the following to your server code.

```
proxy = dataTableProxy("testTable")

observeEvent(input$selectRow, {
    selectRows(proxy, as.numeric(input$selectRow))
})
```